# What is the best way to find an input for a function if you already know the output?

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm working on a fairly complicated program here and unfortunately I've painted myself into a bit of a corner.

I have a function (let's call it f(x) for simplicity) that I know the output value of, and I need to find the input value that generates that output value (to within a certain threshold).

Unfortunately the equations behind f(x) are fairly complicated and I don't have all the information I need to simply run them in reverse- so I'm forced to perform some sort of brute force search to find the right input variable instead.

The outputs for f(x) are guaranteed to be ordered, in such a way that f(x - 1) < f(x) < f(x + 1) is always true.

What is the most efficient way to find the value of x? I'm not entirely sure if this is a "root finding" problem- it seems awfully close, but not quite. I figure there's gotta be some official name for this sort of algorithm, but I haven't been able to find anything on Google.

Comment: Note that your problem can easily be turned into a root finding problem.  If `y` is the known value of `f(x)` for which you are trying to find `x`, then you are trying to find a root of the new function `g(x) = f(x) - y`.  So, you can apply bisection or Brent's method or whatever to the new function `g(x)` to solve your problem.

Comment: How do you know it's possible? If you could always do that, you'd be able to break most hashing and crypto functions

Comment: You haven't given enough information.   Different solution methods are suited to inverting functions with different properties.  For example, what type is `x` and what type does `f()` return?  Is it monotonic?  [your guaranteed order suggests it might be, but there are ways that `f(x-1) < f(x) < f(x+1)` without being monotonic].   Is it continuous?

Comment: What @Leeor says.  A crypro-style trapdoor function is going to be a problem:((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that `x` is an integer so the result `f(x - 1) < f(x) < f(x + 1)` means that the function is strictly *monotonic*.

I'll also assume your function is not pathological, such as

```
f(x) = x * cos(2 * pi * x)
```

which satisfies your property but has all sorts of nasties between integer values of `x`.

A *linear bisection* algorithm is appropriate and tractable here (and you could adapt it to functions which are badly behaved for non-integral `x`), *Brent* might recover the solution faster. Such algorithms may well return you a non-integral value of `x`, but you can always check the integers either side of that, and return the best one (that will work if the function is monotonic in *all* real values of `x`). Furthermore, if you have an analytic *first derivative* of `f(x)`, then an adaption of *Newton Raphson* might work well, constraining `x` to be integral (which might not make much sense, depending on your function; it would be disastrous to apply it to the pathological example above!). Newton Raphson is cute since you only need one starting point, unlike Linear Bisection and Brent which both require the root to be *bracketed*.

Do Google the terms that I've *italicised*.

Reference: [Brent's Method - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method)

Answer (score 1):

For a general function, I would do the following:

1. Evaluate at 0 and determine if `x` is positive or negative.
2. (Assuming positive) . . . Evaluate powers of 2 until you bound the value (1, 2, 4, 8, . . . )
3. Once you have bounds then do repeated bisection until you get the precision you are looking for

If this is being called multiple times, I would cache the values along the way to reduce the time needed for subsequent operations.

Comment: In general this approach can get you into very hot water, but it will always work for a strictly monotonic function. Have an upvote though all the same.

Comment: @Bathsheba . . . The question is about a strictly monotonic function.  I will add, this will work pretty well even when the domain is not real numbers (say integers) and when the function is not continuous (although you obviously cannot get arbitrarily close to all desired values).